# What does "<<" exactly do in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, operators

I am new to Ruby, so I am still learning several things. But, I do have good experience with Java and C.

I would like to know what this does exactly:

```
[ 'a','b', 'c' ].each_with_index {|item, index| result << [item, index] }
```

Specifically, I am interested in the `<<`. Some research tells me that it is used for bit shifting, but it's obvious that is not the case here, so what is it doing here?

Comment: By the way, this is roughly equivalent to the preferrable `results = ['a', 'b', 'c'].each_with_index.to_a`.

Comment: @NiklasB. I'd say it's *exactly* equivalent (and also rather beautiful).

Comment: @Andrew: Only if `results` is empty before... Got yet another one, BTW, which is not so beautiful: `['a', 'b', 'c'].zip(0..(1.0/0))` :D

Comment: @NiklasB. Ah, didn't think of that. But then you could just do `results + [...].each_...`. I like the second one too but I think using `Float::INFINITY` directly would make it a more apparent that you're trying to get an infinite range.

Comment: @Andrew: Yeah, but `Float::INFINITY` simply doesn't type.

Comment: Good question. It is used mainly to inject into a collection. [This](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/22/rubys-splat-operator/) is a fun article that covers some of Rubys fun operators.

Comment: Can someone tell me how can you use << operator on an object to perform something

Answer (score 12):

The `<<` operator is adding items to the result array in this case.

See " [how to add elements to ruby array (solved)](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=22303)".

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby, all the things which are operators in C/Java, like +, -, *, /, and so on, are actually method calls. You can redefine them as desired.

```
class MyInteger
  def +(other)
    42 # or anything you want
  end
end
```

Array defines the `<<` method to mean "push this item on the end of this array". For integers, it's defined to do a bit shift.

Aside from Array, many other classes define `<<` to represent some kind of "appending" operation.

Comment: Caveat: Redefining operators in unexpected ways can lead to code maintenance and debugging problems, and eventually to madness.

Comment: Redefining `+` to always return 42 is definitely mad. (I did try redefining `Fixnum#+` once in `irb`, and `irb` got very messed up.) But defining operators on your custom classes in Ruby isn't necessarily bad; because *all* operators are method calls, when you see an operator, you *expect* that it may be a call to a user-defined method.

Comment: But it is very easy to abuse operator overloading, we learned that lesson in the 90s with C++. Besides, you should be returning 11, no amp goes to 42.

Comment: You are both completely right. I'm just making the point that Ruby "operator overloading" is not *quite* as bad as C++ operator overloading, because you don't have to wonder if a given operator is "really" an operator or whether it is overloaded; you *know* that it is a method call, because *all* operators are method calls.

Answer (score 6):

It's the [Array append operator](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/%3C%3C).

`<<` is a method, and will do different things for different classes. Array uses it to push an object onto the end of an array. [Fixnums use it to shift](http://apidock.com/ruby/Fixnum/%3C%3C).

Answer (score 4):

This is basically an Append Operator.

It was be used with to append either an element to an array or a substring to string

**For Arrays**

1.9.2-p290 :009 > arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

```
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

1.9.2-p290 :010 > arr << 6

```
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

1.9.2-p290 :011 >

**For Strings**

1.9.2-p290 :011 > str = "ruby"

```
=> "ruby"
```

1.9.2-p290 :012 > str << 'rails'

```
=> "rubyrails"
```

1.9.2-p290 :013 >